# Phonegap throws error: FileConstructor is not a constructor for the javascript File API

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

We're trying to test our angular js app built using phonegap in iPad. Here we've used the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) API to upload a blob which is perfectly working in the web app but not in the phonegap based iOS app when tested in iPad.

Here's the code:

```
var base64Img = vm.state.viewer.impl.getScreenShotBuffer();

if (vm.markupVisible) {
    base64Img = getDataFromMarkup();
}

var blob = dataURItoBlob(base64Img);
var file = new File([blob], (new Date() ).getTime() + '.png');

vm.taskDetail.uploadScreenshot(file);
```

We used [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) to check the error and it shows this:

```
Error: FileConstructor is not a constructor (evaluating 'new File([b],(new Date).getTime()+".png")')
takeScreenShot@file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/663538C3-DD2D-45D5-AC56-
```

Not sure exactly what the problem is, but I guess `phonegap` doesn't support the `File` API. 
Is there any workaround for this issue? Do we need any kind of polyfill or some library for the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) API to work in phonegap app?

Comment: Are you using phonegap build?

Comment: Yes, we are using it

Comment: How you build your iOS app in Phonegap build?

Comment: @Div We just update our code then PhoneGap Build makes our `IPA`

Comment: This error occurred on build time? Or it build successfully?

Comment: The build was successful. But the error shows up in the run time in iPad. We just checked the error log with GapDebug https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/

Comment: @Div The error only shows up on run time when the code above with the `File` API is executed.

Comment: why you are creating file using File Api ? 
Why dnt you use phonegap file plugin for it

Comment: @HassanALi Because we have a webapp too and the code was initially written for webapp which we're trying to run on phonegap as well. Is the phonegap file plugin a replacement of the File API for phonegap apps?